# Another very small question with same topic as another one

Tags: discussion

I have another question about the meaning of some very small parameter linked with MDM and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458315/customize-lock-screen-footnote-without-administrator-assistance) question, do I post another question, a comment or do I make it an edit to the question?

The parameter is quite small and I would just like to ask for what it does, I do not think it deserves a question on its own.

Also, the only link with the other question is that it's about MDM (which is quite a large topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do some research first, MDM is fairly well-documented.

A question consisting of, well, several questions runs the risk of getting put on hold due to lack of focus.

More information about how to write good questions can be found in https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error and the pages linked there.

Comment: So I post another one?

Comment: @Thinkr I added a reference to the answer.